# Convert object to array for ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create two global variables
such as `var DiscountRef = {};var shareDetail = [];`
when the user add the form I store all the values in DiscountRef variable such as

```
RefValue = {Mobile:9876543210,Quantity:3}
$scope.shareDetail = Object.Keys(RefValue);//I try Object.entries also
```

when I want to display the data in the table

```
{{shareDetail}}
<div ng-repeat="share in shareDetail">
  {{share.Mobile}}
  {{share.Quantity}}
 
</div>
```

Its displaying empty array

I also try this

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in shareDetail">
    {{key}} : {{value}}
 </div>
```

It will get the result.how can I access particular key value pairs such as MobileNo:9876543210 & Quantity:3

Comment: try this: $scope.shareDetail = [RefValue ];

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.value = {Mobile:9876543210,Quantity:3};
$scope.shareDetail = [];
Object.keys($scope.value).forEach(function(key, value)
{
    $scope.shareDetail.push({"item_name": key, "value": $scope.value[key]});
});
```

Then you can do ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in shareDetail">      
    {{item.item_name}} : {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I already get the result in the above code but I want Mobile,Quantity value  to be used in the a tag such as <a href="{{Mobile.value}}">

Comment: as you have Mobile & Quantity value so what's problem are you facing?

Comment: @Michael I have updated my code, could you please try now and let me know. Thanks

Comment: welcome. @Michael please accept the answer if it works :)